# Issue regarding concatenate videos ffmpeg

Tags: audio, video, filter, ffmpeg, mp4

I want to concatenate 3 videos using ffmpeg. So I did a research on the net and got the required code. But later on I realized that it will not work as the attributes of the video are different and hence I will have to re-encode the videos

So I got this on the internet:-

`ffmpeg -i 1.mp4-i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v] [0:a] [1:v] [1:a] [2:v] [2:a] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4`

But when I ran it,it was SUPER slow. And ffmpeg recommended to add `vsync 2` in the code. I added it in the following manner:-

`ffmpeg -i 1.mp4-i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4 -vsync 2 -filter_complex "[0:v] [0:a] [1:v] [1:a] [2:v] [2:a] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4`

Now the video was processed on time and the result was also fine. But I don't know the meaning of the code. Will someone be kind enough to explain what exactly is happening? (in this way I would be sure that the code will always work for me for all videos)

Answer (score 0):

You have changed your vsync (video syncrhonization iirc) parameter. You can find the documentation for this parameter [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-Advanced-options).
With the option "2" you have set it to : Frames are passed through with their timestamp or dropped so as to prevent 2 frames from having the same timestamp.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But why it made the process faster (without it it was taking almost infinite time) to re-encode the video?